# Stratified Sampling in matlab

Tags: matlab, sampling

Can you please help me to make my random sample function to be stratified sampling?

```
%data has dimension m x 1000
%labels are in dimension m x 1

function [ sample_data, sample_labels ] = sample(data,labels,precentile)
[m,n] = size(labels); 
nRows = int32(m*(precentile/100)); % #rows in new dataset
rndIDX = randperm(m,nRows); %random permutation indexis
sample_data = data(rndIDX, :); 
sample_labels = labels(rndIDX, :);
end
```

in label vector (m x 1) are 31 unique numbers (class labels).
Is there any good method to do this?